# Why can't my ASPX pages access directories on the webserver iteself?

Tags: asp.net, webclient, code-access-security

I have a web client that sends a request in the form of XML to my web server.  The web server creates a (rather large) file and saves it in a cached directory and returns it to the web client through the response stream.  This worked fine the first couple times I tried it, but all of the sudden it stopped working and reported the following exception (wrapped in XML):

```
<error type="System.Security.SecurityException">
  <message>Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.</message>
  <stack-trace><![CDATA[   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at Ionic.Zip.SharedUtilities.CreateAndOpenUniqueTempFile(String dir, Stream& fs, String& filename)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.get_WriteStream()
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save()
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save(String fileName)
   at MyApplication.UpdateItemFiles.GetUpdateContent(XDocument a_xManifest, Stream[] a_arrExtraContent) in C:\Software\MyApplication\Alpha\Web Interface\UpdateItemFiles.aspx.cs:line 265
   at MyApplication.UpdateItemFiles.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Software\MyApplication\Alpha\Web Interface\UpdateItemFiles.aspx.cs:line 31]]></stack-trace>
</error>
```

I don't know much about Code Access Security.  I've even tried to give full control on the directory to Everybody. This isn't a problem as this is a development server and not a public machine. I don't understand why this would work the first couple times, but stop working now.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7 64-bit for both server and client (which are the same machine). I'm using IIS 7.0 and the .Net Framework 3.5.

**Edited 2010/12/13 16:05 EST:**

**I'm getting this error because I'm using the DotNetZip library from Codeplex. Is there a way to add an Assembly to IIS or my configuration?**

Comment: Let me guess, I "should" be using an SQL Server, Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than modify the security settings of your ASP.NET application's user itself, I'd suggest creating a new file access application (maybe Windows service accessible via remoting, maybe WCF), that does the file access.  This application can run using the context it needs for file access.

The ASP.NET application only needs to be able to talk to the file access application.  This way, your concerns are separated out, security is stronger, and you don't have to worry about what account the ASP.NET app is using, or impersonating users, etc.

Comment: Except, I know absolutely nothing about remoting or WCF.

Comment: It's worthwhile to take some time to learn. Even if you don't get too in depth, any good enterprise application has a service layer, and WCF seems to be where .NET remoting is going. In the short term, try Googling for a .NET remoting "hello world" app - there's not a whole lot that needs to happen to create one - just a few classes and a few lines in the app.config for the client and server.

Comment: I sought this path, but was denied.  I found a solution that's ugly but it works.  I like this answer the best, even though I didn't use it.  My solution is below.

Answer (score 1):

Because the user your website is running as has very minimal privs by default. Your best bet is to

1. Create a new user with JUST the privs you need - access to SQL, certain folders, etc.
2. Set your application to run as that user
3. Enable impersonation in web.config

That way you can keep changes to privs local to your app and avoid security problems from other applicaitons running on the same server as the default user.

Comment: This didn't work.  Maybe because I'm using IIS 7.0.  I read in the documentation about the anonymous user IUSR_COMPUTERNAME.  I don't have this user.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the assembly `Iconic.Zip` that I was using to create Zip archives. IIS server was not trusting it, and so it wasn't passing code access security checks.  My solution was to create streams from within my own code.  The downside of this, was that I had to leave the streams open until I saved the archive because the `ZipFile` type does all of the reading and writing at one time.